# Is it possible to get the current <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, element

I have a page for example:

```
<body>
<script>Other js code</script>
<hr>
...
<script src="path/{the name can be different}.js"></script>
...
<hr>
...
<script>Other js code</script>
</body>
```

My {the name can be different}.js script block can be inserted anyware and contains:

```
(function () {

   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      element = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
      console.log(element) 
      // ? How to get current script tag
   }, false); 
})();
```

This code always get the latest  tag.
Is it possible to get current script tag without any script id?

Thanks!

Comment: `parent script tag` What do you mean?

Comment: I mean current script tag.

Comment: In your specific case you just need to remove `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {` wrapper.

Comment: Why should I remove this?

Comment: @user889349 You said you want current tag. So get the current tag at the moment of execution, don't delay until every other is loaded.

Comment: @user889349: Because at the moment the callback is executed, the `script` tag that contained the code might not be the last processed `script` tag anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Give your script tag an Id and get the element as following

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="script">
    function getScript()
     {
        var scripts = document.getElementById('script');
        alert(scripts);
     }

</script>
```

Comment: What is this `$(...).ready(...)` thing? It's not native JavaScript.

Comment: I am sorry was trying it out in a page which has jQuery. Have editted the code and thanks for letting me know.